# need to create popover on click on bar in nvd3 js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, uipopovercontroller, uipopover, bootstrap-popover

I want to create a popover ontime of click event in bar charts. i am creating bar charts using nvd3.

```
chart.multibar.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(d,element) {
 $('nvd3 .nv-multibar .nv-groups rect:hover').popover({
       'trigger':'hover'
       ,'container': 'body'
       ,'placement': 'top'
       ,'white-space': 'nowrap'
       ,'show': true
       ,'html':'true'
    });  }
```

but this popover is not working!! 
any help please......?